# Line break being inserted into jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got a strange one and am hoping someone can shed some light on how to fix this. Here is the problem...

I have some javascript code in my razor page which is formatted correctly. Here is the code...

```
$("#ddlMake").change(function ()
{
    var selectedMake = $("#ddlMake").val();
    $.getJSON('/Valuation/ModelRanges', { manufacturerId: selectedMake }, function (ranges)
    {
        var ddlModelRanges = $("#ddlModelRanges");
        ddlModelRanges.empty();
        $.each(ranges, function (index, range)
        {
            ddlModelRanges.append($("<option />", { value: range.value, text: range.text }));
        });
    });
});
```

I am getting a string not terminated error which is totally messing up my page. The code in the browser looks like this...

```
$("#ddlMake").change(function ()
{
    var selectedMake = $("#ddlMake").val();
    $.getJSON('/Valuation/ModelRanges', { manufacturerId: selectedMake }, function (ranges)
    {
        var ddlModelRanges = $("#ddlModelRanges");
        ddlModelRanges.empty();
        $.each(ranges, function (index, range)
        {
            ddlModelRanges.append($("<option />
            ", { value: range.value, text: range.text }));
        });
    });
});
```

For some reason a line break is being inserted into the code before the terminating quote on the option selector. Any ideas as to why this would happen are most welcome. Thanks in advance for your help... :-)

Comment: Not sure if the space here `$("<option />"` matters! Try removing it.

Comment: I always believed the space was needed however I tried that and no joy.

Comment: What's very frustrating is that there are two more code blocks identical to this one that sit below it and they are formatted just fine. To say it's driving me nuts is an understatement.

Comment: If you could recreate the problem in a JSFiddle it would be a huge help

Comment: Okay, I pasted the entire page of code into jsfiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/g1uLsdvd/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try to retype this part `$("<option />"`. There could be some invisible character

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/g1uLsdvd/2/

Please put your html in the above link and test... and let me know what issue you get.. I think there is no issue with your js code... try once your html and js in the above link and run the code... by click in the menu item run... hope you will find your issue or resolve ...

the below code looks fe with no error...

```
$("#ddlMake").change(function ()
{
    var selectedMake = $("#ddlMake").val();
    $.getJSON('/Valuation/ModelRanges', { manufacturerId: selectedMake }, function (ranges)
    {
        var ddlModelRanges = $("#ddlModelRanges");
        ddlModelRanges.empty();
        $.each(ranges, function (index, range)
        {
            ddlModelRanges.append($("<option />", { value: range.value, text: range.text }));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: When I try that link, in the result box it gives me the following with the option removed...

$("#ddlMake").change(function () { var selectedMake = $("#ddlMake").val(); $.getJSON('/Valuation/ModelRanges', { manufacturerId: selectedMake }, function (ranges) { var ddlModelRanges = $("#ddlModelRanges"); ddlModelRanges.empty(); $.each(ranges, function (index, range) { ddlModelRanges.append($("", { value: range.value, text: range.text })); }); }); });

Comment: i have edited my answer and updated the link.. please check again in that link by put ur html and run... hope it helps you...

Comment: I did as you asked, here is the new link to jsfiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/g1uLsdvd/3/

Comment: please put javascript in left side 2nd box and html in left side first box without <html> tag... then run and see output.. it is trwoing error... ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g1uLsdvd/4/
i have modified some code in the above link.. bcz javascript must be written in another box of javascript and script, html, head , meta tags are not needed andn ot allowed in html box.. try ur code again and try if it working...

Comment: If you run the jshint at the code it shows the error but this is the code that is being sent to the browser. Is that the error you are talking about

Comment: no there is no error in your code... just remove the extra space in ddlModelRanges.append($("<option />",..

I mean just see if dere is some extar space or new line had put by mistake after or before the closing of (") sign

Comment: You cannot modify code that is already sent to the browser. My code on the server side is fine.  It is when the page is served and rendered by the browser that the spaces and carriage return are being inserted. I just cannot work out why it is happening. When you look at the two code blocks below this problematic one they are fine.

Comment: As I have tried the code in my html file and try to load it on firebox browser.. it shows no error dear...